# How to remove space of url %20 on Nginx System?

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect URLs like domain.com/stack%20over%20flow to domain.com/stack-over-flow.

I use Nginx, thus, I can't use .htacess based solutions.

How can I achieve this with Nginx?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912191/how-to-replace-underscore-to-dash-with-nginx?lq=1