# nginx replace wrong UTF characters in URL

Tags: nginx, unicode, url-rewriting

I have webserver with `nginx`.

In HTML pages, I have lots of urls like: köln.jpg, münchen.jpg, köln-münchen.jpg. I can not edit the pages.

However on the disk some files are stored as "koln.jpg" or munchen or koln-munchen.jpg. I can not rename the files.

I basically need if image file is not found, file to be look as follows:

```
ö -> o
ü -> u
ä -> a
```

also same for caps - Ä -> A etc.

At the moment I am thinking to implement simple `PHP script` that doing this, if there is 404 error, using `nginx` `404 document`.

However I am thinking there might be easier way using `nginx` rewrite.

This question is somehow related, but is not the same:
[How to replace underscore to dash with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912191/how-to-replace-underscore-to-dash-with-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to handle such requests with rewrite_by_lua statement. 
[here](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqset_uri) is detailed documentation with clear example.